# add watermark to powerpoint

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint, watermark, office-automation

I want to add watermark to powerpoint file from c# by using powerpoint object library but I could not find any example/documentation which explains how to do it.

Is it possible at all? Any hints or suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make add Shape, set `TextFrame.TextRange.Text` to some string, set `TextFrame.TextRange.Font` to something big, rotate the shape, and send it to back.

Comment: That indeed sounds like it would work. You should set the text to a light color, like gray.

Comment: Watermarks are also WordArt, but the concept is the same as SLaks describes. Also, if you're adding to all slides, you may want to just add the shape to the Master instead of each slide seperately.